# Center Text on a Button

Tags: css, button, center

I know this has been asked a couple of times before, but not of the solutions seem to be working in this case. Basically, I want the word "play" to be centered vertically and horizontally on this button. Horizontally, the text behaves itself, but vertically, not matter what I try, it is *always* a little bit lower than it should, in all browsers I test it on. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

```
<style type="text/css">
button {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: white;
border-style: none;
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
}

button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner /*Remove button padding in FF*/
{ 
border: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.start {
background-color: #0C0;
font-size: 2em;
padding: 10px;

}


</style>
<button type="button" class="start">play</button>
```

Comment: it's just because the text is lower case.  http://jsfiddle.net/TYZX4/1/

Comment: Good spot, though I've just measured it on photoshop and the upper case version is still not in the exact center. Perhaps I'm being too picky...

Comment: yeah then at that point, the only thing you can do is use something like 
`padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;` http://jsfiddle.net/TYZX4/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `padding` on .start is likely what you'll have to play around with, although the way it's set, it should be centering it, but you can break it out to something like `padding: 8px 10px 10px 10px;`

You might also check and set the `line-height` under .start and see if it helps.

Comment: It seems like the default centering just isn't precise enough so although not quite as elegant, this method certainly gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct value for `vertical-align` is `middle`, not `center`. However I'm not sure if that'll make the difference, because it might just affect where the button itself is aligned vertically relative to surrounding text. I'm pretty sure button text is vertically centered by default, though...